# Text parsing with specific element Python

Tags: python-3.x, parsing

I have an aligment result with multiple sequences as text file. I want to split each result into new text file. Far now I can detect each sequence with '>', and split into files. However, new text files writen without line that contains '>'.

```
with open("result.txt",'r') as fo:
    start=0
    op= ' '
    cntr=1
    # print(fo.readlines())
    for x in fo.readlines():
        # print(x)
        if (x[0]== '>'):
            if (start==1):
                with open(str(cntr)+'.txt','w') as opf:
                    opf.write(op)
                    opf.close()
                    op= ' '
                    cntr+=1
            else:
                start=1   
        else:
            if (op==''):
                op=x
            else:
                op= op + '\n' + x
    fo.close()
    print('completed')
```

```
>P51051.1 RecName: Full=Melatonin receptor type 1B; Short=Mel-1B-R; Short=Mel1b 
receptor [Xenopus laevis]
Length=152
```

this is how I want to see as a beginning of each text file but they start as

```
receptor [Xenopus laevis]
Length=152
```

How can I include from the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
with open("result.txt", encoding='utf-8') as fo:
    for index, txt in enumerate(fo.read().split(">")):
        if txt:
            with open(f'{index}.txt', 'w') as opf:
                opf.write(txt)
```

You should provide the encoding of the file e.g. `utf-8`, no need to specify read `r`, there is no need to close the file if you are using a context manager i.e. `with` and you just need to use `read` instead of `readlines` to get a string then call `split` on the string. I'm using `enumerate` to get a counter as well as enumerate objects. And f-string as it is a better way for string concatenation.